# Google Social Graph API, working as intended?

Tags: api, social-networking

I'm experiencing some problems with Google's social graph API. It seems that for some parameters passed to 'otherme' nothing is returned. I'll use Robert Scoble's profiles as an example (as he's a guy sure to be everywhere on the web). If I query:

http://socialgraph.apis.google.com/otherme?q=http://twitter.com/scobleizer&pretty=1

I get results, as expected.
However, if I query:

http://socialgraph.apis.google.com/otherme?q=http://delicious.com/scobleizer&pretty=1

Nothing is returned, even though 'http://delicious.com/scobleizer' is listed in the previous results...

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get more from the main 'lookup' function ('otherme' is something like syntactic sugar, whereas 'lookup' exposes more raw functionality),

http://socialgraph.apis.google.com/lookup?q=http://delicious.com/scobleizer&fme=1&edi=1&edo=1&pretty=1&callback=

...but yeah, no sign of that specific Twitter URL. Probably worth reporting on the list:

http://groups.google.com/group/social-graph-api